# Passing Parameters to a function on an onChange Event along with field data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update the products price and total cost based on any products quantity getting changed which is done via a text field which has minimum and maximum quantities.Sp when the quantity changes,i will get the updated quantity and price for that product on the backend and update it appropriately on the frontend.So i tried to use an anonymous function and pass the parameters to another function but i get an error saying that e.target.value is undefined.Here is the code i have written/tried so far.

```
import React from 'react'
import App from './App'
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie'
import './view_cart.css'
import {ToastContainer, toast,style} from 'react-toastify'

var hiding='';
class View_cart extends React.Component
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state={item_list:{},"total_items_price":'',product_count:''}
    this.view_cart_details=this.view_cart_details.bind(this)
    this.delete_item_cart=this.delete_item_cart.bind(this)
    this.product_state=this.product_state.bind(this)
  }

  registeration_notification(value_to_render)
  {
    toast(value_to_render,
      {
        //position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
        autoClose: 3000,
      }
    );
  }

  product_state(e,product_name,manufacturer)
  {
    this.setState({"product_count":e.target.value})
    console.log(this.state.product_count)
    console.log(product_name,manufacturer)
  }

  display_cart()
  {
    //console.log(Object.keys(this.state.item_list))
    const mapping = Object.keys(this.state.item_list).map((item,id) =>
    {
      console.log(this.state.item_list[item]['image_path'])
      var location = require('./Images/'.concat(this.state.item_list[item]['image_path']))
      //console.log(location)
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="container">
            <table id="cart" className="table table-hover table-condensed">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th style={{width:50}}>Product</th>
                  <th style={{width:10}}>Price</th>
                  <th style={{width:8}}>Quantity</th>
                  <th style={{width:22}} className="text-center">Subtotal</th>
                  <th style={{width:10}}></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td data-th="Product">
                    <div className="row">
                      <div className="col-sm-2 hidden-xs"><img src={location} alt="..." className="img-responsive"/></div>
                      <div className="col-sm-8">
                        <h4 className="nomargin">{this.state.item_list[item]["Name"]} {'by '.concat(this.state.item_list[item]["manufacturer"])}</h4>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="Price">{this.state.item_list[item]["original_price"]}</td>
                  <td data-th="Quantity">
                    <input type="number" min="1" max="10" value={this.state.product_count} onChange={(e) => this.product_state(this.state.item_list[item]['Name'],this.state.item_list[item]['manufacturer'],e)} placeholder="Min 1 Max 10" className="form-control text-center"/>
                  </td>
                  <td data-th="Subtotal" className="text-center">{this.state.item_list[item]['price']}</td>
                  <td className="actions" data-th="">
                    <button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"  style ={{hiding}} onClick={() =>this.delete_item_cart(this.state.item_list[item]['Name'],this.state.item_list[item]['manufacturer'])}><i className="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
          )
    })
  return mapping
}

  sample_string()
  {
    console.log("ONCLICK WORKING")
  }
  sample_cookie_output()
  {
    const test_cookie_testing = new Cookies();

    var auth_string='Token '
    console.log((auth_string.concat(test_cookie_testing.get('Authorization'))),typeof((auth_string.concat(test_cookie_testing.get('Authorization')))))
    return (auth_string.concat(test_cookie_testing.get('Authorization')))
  }

  delete_item_cart(product_name_delete,manufacturer_name)
  {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/delete_item_cart/',
    {
      method:"POST",
      headers:
      {
      'Content-Type':"application/json",
      "Accept":"application/json",
      "Authorization":this.sample_cookie_output()
    },
      body:JSON.stringify({"product_name":product_name_delete,"manufacturer":manufacturer_name})

  })
  .then(something =>something.json())
  .then(findResponse =>
    {
      console.log(findResponse,typeof(findResponse))
      if((Object.keys(findResponse).length)===1 && (Object.keys(findResponse).includes("Data Deletion")))
      {
        hiding='displayNone';
        console.log(hiding)
        //console.log("A user with this name already exists.")
        this.registeration_notification("The Product has been removed from the cart")
      }
    }
  )
  }

  view_cart_details()
  {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/view_cart/',
    {
      method:"GET",
      headers:
      {
        'Content-Type':"application/json",
      "Accept":"application/json",
      "Authorization":this.sample_cookie_output()
    },
  })
.then(something =>something.json())
.then(findResponse =>
  {
    console.log(findResponse)
    this.setState({"item_list":findResponse[0],"total_items_price":findResponse[1]})
  }

)
  }

componentDidMount(){
  this.view_cart_details()
}

render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <App/>
      {this.display_cart()}
      <button onClick={this.delete_item_cart}>Test Button</button>
      <ToastContainer/>
    </div>
  )
}
}

export default View_cart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `e` parameter at third place and in the function you are trying to access it from the first parameter. Pass `e` as first parameter

```
onChange={(e) => this.product_state(e, this.state.item_list[item]['Name'],this.state.item_list[item]['manufacturer'])}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<button onClick={(e) => this.delete_item_cart(e)}>Test Button</button>
```

Comment: The `delete_item_cart` function does not appear to accept an Event as an argument

Comment: The function in consideration is the product_state function which is getting called on an onChange event.

Answer (score 1):

Change e param position

```
product_state(e,product_name,manufacturer)
```

to

```
product_state(product_name,manufacturer,e)
```